# YouTube feed for a show?

Tags: youtube, feeds, url

Rather than subscribe (in my feed reader) to my YouTube feed of subscribed things (which bunches everything into one big stream), I'd like to subscribe (again, in my feed reader) to each of the things I'm interested in on YouTube *separately*. When interested in all the content from one *user*, the feed URL is simply

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/users/[user]/uploads
```

I've been trying to figure out how to get the feed for [Freeman's Mind](https://www.youtube.com/show/freemansmind), but no luck. I've tried the following links:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/show/freemansmind
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/shows/freemansmind
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/show/freemansmind
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/shows/freemansmind
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/users/machinima/show/freemansmind
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/users/machinima/shows/freemansmind
```

Is there a feed for shows, or one which would almost uniquely identify only the contents of the show, such as *user=machinima; title contains "Freeman's Mind"*?

---

Based on the answers I have developed a [bookmarklet to go to the relevant feed of a video or channel](https://gitlab.com/victor-engmark/YouTube-channel-web-feed-bookmarklet).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer (the feed for Freeman's Mind) is:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/49C3B7EDD1624C55
```

The longer answer (to find this on your own): you need to go onto the creator's account page and click on the playlist for the show you want.  The playlist ID (in this case, 49C3B7EDD1624C55) is found above the list of episodes, at the end of the URL box for the show.

You can then either plug that playlist ID into the end of the URL I gave you above, or if you want to do it on your own, go to [YouTube's page for finding feeds](http://gdata.youtube.com/demo/index.html), select "Get" in the Playlist section, and the input the ID you've found in the box.  It then outputs the URI for the feed below.

Below is a screenshot of the feed page.

[image]

Comment: This method no longer works. I can't seem to get a playlist ID out of a show - they no longer link back to the creator's page.

Comment: You might have to fiddle around (some shows have a link in the right-hand column for a link to the creator, or search the site for the creator's name, etc.). Once you're on the creator's main page, go to **Browse Videos** then **Playlists**, and then follow @Leonick's answer below on the url of the playlist you want.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Youtube Data API to retrieve the feed of all of the episodes. The key is to use the special category of 'Shows':

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?
    q=freemansmind
    &orderby=published
    &author=machinima
    &category=Shows
    &v=2
```

Answer (score 1):

This is more so a comment than an answer since we already have a correct answer anyway.

However, I just wanted to leave a note here that that when you browse YouTube to get your playlist ID from the URL they are a bit tricky.

If you go to a playlist for example: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL26D021A7580EA83F
The last part of it is as said in the correct answer the playlist ID, however if you take `PL26D021A7580EA83F` and input that in [gdata.youtube.com](http://gdata.youtube.com/) you will be told it's invalid. What you have to do is remove the first two letters in the ID, the `PL`, so `PL26D021A7580EA83F` becomes `26D021A7580EA83F`. After that it will work.