# How do I subscribe to a YouTube playlist?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

Let's say there's a channel that churns out a lot of content, but I am only interested in a subset of it. That content cannot be made into a show, as per some YouTube guideline or whatever, but the channel owner helpfully compiles it into a playlist.

I know it's possible to subscribe to a show, but what about a playlist?

(I actually remember doing so about 3 design iterations back, but I can't find it now.)

Answer (score 9):

I'd make 2 changes to @eisb's suggestion:

1. That is an invalid playlist Id, so try "8DCB3F2E1AF98B48" (Cronoslogic's 'Hubble Space Telescope' series), but more importantly
2. Use '**base**' rather than 'api' in the URL, e.g http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/playlists/8DCB3F2E1AF98B48

In the [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html#Projection_Values), it says "Similarly, if you prefer to use the base projection, which is well suited to feed readers, you can substitute base for api in any of the sample requests described in the API documentation." It seems the api projection is more for developers.

I've just added that to Google Reader and it works fine.

Comment: Good point on 'base' vs. 'api'. +1

Comment: Actually `api` produced exactly the same visual output in feedly as `base` did for me. And the playlist ID that @eisb mentioned that you can get from the Share button works just fine.

Comment: The "gdata" RSS URLs no longer seem to work.  ATTOW, this answer works for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30317505

Answer (score 8):

For subscribing to a playlist through a feed reader (not within your YouTube account) the answer builds on the answer to a similar question [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/21335/13194), but with YouTube's recent layout revamp, an slight update to that answer is necessary.

Go to the user's page and click on their Videos tab and then the Playlists link on the left side to see the list of their playlists. Go into the playlist you want, and then click on the Share button. The link it gives you should look something like this: `http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4CB4E2B35919DD4B`. After the `=` are two letters (most likely `PL`) -- copy everything after those two letters and paste it at the end of the following link:

`http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/`

This is your RSS feed to subscribe to the playlist in the feed reader of your choice.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution no longer works, server just responds with "410 Gone"

Answer (score 0):

Using this service you can
[Subscribe youtube playlist | Listabell](https://www.listabell.com)

It is also easy to use.

1. Create an activate your account.
2. Start adding your favorite playlists.
3. Get notified when a playlist is updated.

If you like the service and want me to keep developing it and keep it running please consider donating and sending your suggestions.