# How to get YouTube show RSS

Tags: youtube, rss

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [YouTube feed for a show?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/20770/youtube-feed-for-a-show)

I want to get rss for [Gamespot Reviews](http://www.youtube.com/show/gamespotreviews).

But when I try to add the links to rss, youtube pointed to

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/users/gamespot/uploads?alt=rss&v=2&orderby=published&client=ytapi-youtube-profile
```

URL, which list every video uploaded by Gamespot, which is very annoying as hell.

How can I get rss for a single show?

Comment: i did see that thread. unfortunately it doesnt work as there is no playlist for the show. have you actually try the method in that thread(to find the playlist id)?

Comment: here what i found by doing what that thread suggested. http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/E3C1CD2F32F92409
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/FF8380C9F3992BF8
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/FE2803B118BDB381
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/8B8911E86B7B0CAF
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/645D603FDCEBEBF2. unfortunately, all playlist are for year before 2012. i did find playlist for 2012 http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=EL8YDywF75jTA&page=1 . unfortunately, the playlist id is somewhat different, thus i cannot add that to rss.

Comment: What are you trying to do with it? RSS is not for a single video

Comment: who says i want a single video? are you on crack? quit trolling. jeeezaz

Answer (score 0):

As described in the second answer to [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/21334/16377), you can use the API to build an RSS. This works by searching for review, does it show what you are after?

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=reviews&orderby=published&author=gamespot&category=Shows&v=2
```

Comment: as you can see by following that link, "GameSpot Now Playing - Battlefield 3: Armored Kill DLC" is not a review. that means, that link doesnt work... perfect. it does show review videos, plus many others that are not relevant.